# ajaxful-rating :static param is not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am using the ajaxful-rating ruby gem to allow users to vote for some items and it is working well - except when I try to pass :static param. When I do this, I get the following error:

> uninitialized constant AjaxfulRating::StarsBuilder::MissingRateRoute

Some help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a rate route for your User model. For example:
`match "/users/:id/rate", :to => "users#rate", :as => "rate_user", :via => :post`